Why does my Expo Camera not work for React Native?
My expo camera is not working. Whenever I try to run the code it gives me a "Unable to resolve a module expo-camera from (my path), expo camera could not be found within the project or in these directories: node_modules."
I tried Npm install to get all of the packages and then the message said "ConfigError: The expected package.json path: (path) does not exist"
I tried reinstalling as well as npm install

it will better if you share your expo and react-native version and make sure to add this to your app.json file
"expo": {
"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-camera",
    {
      "cameraPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your camera",
      "microphonePermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your microphone",
      "recordAudioAndroid": true
    }
  ]
]

}
add permission check on your project / component

const [permission, requestPermission] = Camera.useCameraPermissions();
check the permission with a console.log(permission.granted)

if this returnd false then add below code to show user to allow this
if (!permission.granted) {
// Camera permissions are not granted yet
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>We need your permission to show the camera</Text>
    <Button onPress={requestPermission} title="grant permission" />
  </View>
);

}
